# Removing orelse and andalso in long guards

Tags: erlang

I'm writing a function in erlang which should be able to accept various sets of parameters in different orders and in different formats and I'm using very strict guards to ensure correct matching.

It is not uncommon for me to write a long guard like this:

```
my_fun(List, Number, OptionalList, Record)
when is_list(List) andalso length(List) >= 5, 
     is_integer(Number) andalso Number >= 10 andalso Number =< 50 orelse Number =:= undefined, 
     is_list(OptionalList) orelse OptionalList =:= undefined, 
     is_record(Record, my_record) ->
```

I am using orelse and andalso a lot here and it makes code a lot less readable and just generally longer.

Is there a way to implement the same guard logic using , and ; only?

Comment: Consider using macros? `when ?is_integer_in_range(Number, 10, 50)`, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you'll need to keep some of the `orelse` and `andalso`, since when using `,` and `;`, you essentially have a number of alternatives (separated by `;`) consisting of several conditions (separated by `,`), and *every* condition in at least one of the alternatives must be true.  In this example, you have almost the opposite situation: for each argument, you want *one* of the conditions to be true.

In other words, a guard like this:

```
A, B; C, D
```

is (almost<sup>1</sup>) equivalent to:

```
(A andalso B) orelse (C andalso D)
```

and there is no way to do something like `(A orelse B) andalso (C orelse D)` without using these operators.

You can make this example a bit shorter, though:

- `is_list(List)` is superfluous, since `length(List)` will fail if `List` is not a list.  In a guard, "failing" does not mean throwing an error; it just means that the clause doesn't match.
- `is_integer(Number)` is *almost* superfluous, since you also have `Number >= 10 andalso Number =< 50`.  In Erlang, any two terms can be compared for size, so if `Number` is within this range, it's definitely a number. (It could be a floating-point number instead of an integer, though.)
- Instead of `is_record(Record, my_record)`, you could match for a record in the function head:

  ```
  my_fun(List, Number, OptionalList, Record = #my_record{})
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup> If `A` or `B` would throw an exception, the `orelse` version would not match, while the `;` version would match if the `C, D` portion would match.  For example, this function returns `b`:

```
foo() when 1/0 == 1 orelse true ->
    a;
foo() when 1/0 == 1; true ->
    b.
```